# Grails Spring security - Can you change auth responses based on the request header, forward to login page for html req return 401 code for json req

Tags: web-services, authentication, grails, spring-security

I have a grails app configured with spring security, when I access via a browser and am not authenticated it redirects me to the login page. If I access a JSON webservice within the app it doesnt give an authentication error as the response it returns the html login page to the client.

Is it possible to define different authentication methods based on if the client is requesting html vs json? i.e. return a response code of 401 if requesting JSON and not authenticated?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure your own Failure Handler, default handler makes this redirection. To make this you have to register bean with name `authenticationFailureHandler` that implements `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationFailureHandler`. It's undocumented, but I'm sure that it works. You can send 401 from here, redirect, continue processing, etc.